# Ali's letter to his son - authentic?

Tags: authenticity, ali, isnad

Is the famous letter (filled with parental advice) attributed from Ali to his son al-Hasan an authentic piece? I am not aware of an isnad or a physical manuscript. Here's a link: https://www.al-islam.org/articles/letter-father-son-last-will-ali-ibn-abi-talib